# I need an easy way to detect CSS3 media query support using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries, browser-detection

I need a quick and dirty way to detect media query support using jquery. I defined a function as follows:

```
function mediaQueriesEnabled () {
   var v = parseFloat($.browser.version);
   if ($.browser.msie) {
      if (v < 9)
         return (false);
   }
   return (true);
}
```

Can someone help me fix this up a bit? Looking at this page:

http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries

I realized that there are some complexities here. For example, when I test my version of safari, I get "534.57.2". I want to avoid installing modernizr for now, mainly because I'm in a crunch and I need to handle most situations in the short term. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Modernizr is AFAIK the fastest way to go. Just link and test a variable.

Comment: or you can just kick IE<9 using conditional HTML and assume the rest are good to go.

Comment: You should definitely use feature detection for this, don't just exclude IE versions less than 9. Also, if you *just* need this feature then please don't use Modernizr; Sandy Gifford's answer works great and is much more lightweight.

Comment: I ended up needing modernizr for other things, which what I'm using now. Before that, I used @Niet's answer, which worked great.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a stylesheet with a media query and see if it works.

In your HTML:

```
<style>@media all and (min-width:1px) {
    .mediatest {position:absolute}
}</style>
```

(Or you could dynamically create the stylesheet, but that's harder)

Then in your script:

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.className = "mediatest";
document.body.appendChild(d);
if( window.getComputedStyle && window.getComputedStyle(d).position == "absolute") {
    // supports media queries!
}
document.body.removeChild(d);
```

Comment: Just want to throw out there, that although my answer has more votes, if you *can* use this one, use it.  It's super fool-proof.  If you want a pure, javascript-only solution, by all means use mine; if you're not that crazy, this is what you should be using.

Answer (score 14):

**EDIT:  I'm  no longer curating this answer as I feel that Niet's is much better (see chosen answer).**  It should still work, but may need some testing.

Cracking open [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) (which can test for media queries) we see it uses the `window.matchMedia` ([MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.matchMedia)) function.  We can check in plain old vanilla JS to see if this function exists:

```
function mediaQueriesEnabled () {
    if(typeof window.matchMedia != "undefined" || typeof window.msMatchMedia != "undefined") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or more elegantly:

```
function mediaQueriesEnabled () {
    return (typeof window.matchMedia != "undefined" || typeof window.msMatchMedia != "undefined");
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PzegV/10/)

I've tested in the following browsers that support media queries, all correctly returned true:

- Safari Mobile
- Chrome 26

I've tested in the following browsers that do not support media queries, all correctly returned false:

- IE 7

Comment: Good to know... I am definitely leaning towards using a library as I don't think there's any JS standard for this yet.

Comment: @Redtopia remembering that (A) all libraries are at some point made up of standard JS, and (B) that I'm pretty sure that the code I gave you is fool proof, I'm not quite positive what you mean by no "JS standard" method.  I'd be glad to add more detail if it'll help.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that your answer is incorrect. I'm only stating my preference to use a framework for HTML5/CSS3 stuff rather than write pure JS code because it often takes more time to testing various browser support. Frameworks are good, IMHO. Your code may be spot on! I did vote you up for your effort!

Comment: Thank you =)  I'm an old stubborn vanilla JS guy.  It's gotten me in deep as often as it has gotten me out.

Comment: Updated based on a small discussion on a very similar answer I gave here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807088/how-can-i-detect-via-javascript-if-browser-supports-css3-media-queries-and-css3/17203057#17203057

Comment: This code gives "not supported" for IE9, although it does support media queries. Seems to work fine for other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some working code that is based on @Kolink's answer. So far this code works great... I'll post back to this thread if I have any edits.

The Javascript:

```
var $globals = {
    mediaQuerySupport: false
}

function initMediaQueries () {
    // tests for media query support
    $globals.mediaQuerySupport = false;
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    d.className = "mediatest"; // found in core.css
    document.body.appendChild(d);
    if( window.getComputedStyle && window.getComputedStyle(d).position == "absolute") {
        $mlGlobals.mediaQuerySupport = true;
        mlDebug ('browser has media query support');
    }
    document.body.removeChild(d);
}

function mediaQueriesEnabled () {
   return ($globals.mediaQuerySupport);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    initMediaQueries();
    if (mediaQueriesEnabled()) {
        ... do something
    }
});
```

The CSS (I added this to my main stylesheet file):

```
@media all and (min-width:1px) {
    .mediatest {position:absolute}
}
```