# How to make a mobile app so that it's UI will be compatible in maximum devices?

Tags: cordova, cross-browser

I have idea about cordova. I am trying to use jQuery mobile framework but still not getting good result.

Comment: This is to broad. Be more specific. What exactly are you trying to achive. What is the actual result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** Facebook uses User-Agent string to detect browser and open specific website as [touch.facebook.com](http://touch.facebook.com)(for touch devices), [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com)(other devices), [m.facebook.com](http://m.facebook.com)(for mobile devices). They have specific team to work on new/old/modified User-Agent-String, as new mobile launched or updated.

---

As it is too broad question so that, i am just giving my idea as a general-answer. This will help in understanding the concept of cross-device websites/web-applications:

Now days we have various type of devices like PCs, Tablets, Smart Phones, Feature Pones, Normal Phones etc. But main point to keep in mind is that our web-application will run on **a browser** AND on PC we can have a browser(or emulation to a browser by developer tool) which have low in feature. So main thing is that, **we need to understand browsers.**

**So,** As you know a browser can understand 3 languages: HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Now, My idea is to create two website code, one for mobile[**M**] (only HTML) and second Responsive design[**R**] ([bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) can be use). Next follow this strategy:

Set site **M** as default and add `<script>` tag with code of permanent-redirection to **R** site. If browser supports JavaScript then site **R** will handle everything else.

---

**Points:**

- If you think script code will be displayed on low-end-mobile for site **M** as simple-text, then you can use FONT tag to set font-size as zero. BTW, redirection code will be very less and [this article](http://gabesumner.com/how-many-web-browsers-support-responsive-design) shows there are **75% browsers supports Responsive website design** today.
- If website redirects to site **R** that means its supports JavaScript. Now, if you want separate site for browser which dose not support Responsive Design(site **R**, BTW it will we displayed fine) you can look in to [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665697/i-need-an-easy-way-to-detect-css3-media-query-support-using-jquery) to detect **R** support by JavaScript.